# SQL - filtering by children (or foreign key)

Tags: sql

I am using SQLite

Assume I have 2 tables:

```
Table 1 - person

| id | username | email          |
| 1  | jdoe     | jd@email.com   | 
| 2  | jane     | jane@email.com |


Table 2 - survey

| id | answered_survey | date       | person.id |
| 1  | no              | 01/01/2019 | 1         |
| 2  | yes             | 01/05/2019 | 1         |
| 3  | no              | 01/06/2019 | 2         |
```

I'd like to do something like: Show me every `person` that does not have any children with `yes` in the `answered_survey` column.

I'm stuck with trying to query by "person does not have any children with X value in Y column", I just keep getting "show me any `person` that has a child with `no` in `answered_survey`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option with `not exists`.

```
select *
from person p
where not exists (select 1 
                  from survey s 
                  where p.id = s.personid
                  and s.answered_survey = 'yes'
                 )
```

Comment: what does the `1` in `select 1` refer to?

Comment: @MorganAllen: nothing actually, you can replace it with `*` if you like - `exists` only tests for the presence of a row, not for the actual values returned by the sub-query. It's a performance myth that `select 1` is faster in that situation than `select *`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM person 
 WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT personid
      FROM survey 
     WHERE answered_survey = 'yes'
);
```

If you need only the `id`’s,

```
SELECT id FROM person 
EXCEPT 
SELECT DISTINCT personid FROM survey WHERE answered_survey = 'yes';
```

is even simpler, but the two `SELECT`’s must return comparable records (same number of fields with same types), hence we must restrict to `id` and `personid`.